# rails activerecord scope join query get records that don't exist in join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this activerecord scope query:

`scope :manageable_users, -> { joins(:roles).where.not(roles: { role_name: 'admin' }) }`

where I want `manageable_users` to return all users who are not admins. However, some users do not have entries in the `roles` table (i.e they are not admins, but they do not have any other special roles either) How do I get the query to return those users as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default joins in rails perform an INNER JOIN.

For your use case, where you want to fetch users even if they do not have associated value in roles, use LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN roles on roles.user_id = users.id")
```

In Rails 5 you can do:

```
User.left_outer_joins(:roles)
```